# Reading NSUserDefault key data into UITableView

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

How can I read/load data from a key into a UITableView? When I run `println(keyData1)` I get output `[data1, data2, data3]`. How can I add this data to a UITableView? The UIViewTable read data from "`var mineSpillere`".

This is how i read the data:

```
if let testArray : AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("YourKey") {
    var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as! [NSString]
    println(readArray)
    // Here i want to add the "readArray" to my UITableView.
}
```

Maybe something like this:

```
var mineSpillere = readArray // This will make mineSpiller same as readArray?
```

Comment: Consult the documentation of `UITableViewController`. You need to implement the table view's `datasource`.

Answer (score 0):

In your table view's data source (which is usually the `UITableViewController` that contains the table, but can be any class that implements `UITableViewDataSource`), override

`numberOfSectionsInTableView()` (in your case, this should probably return `1`);

`tableView(_, numberOfRowsInSection:)` to return the size of the `NSUserDefaults` array; and

`tableView(_, cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` to return a `UITableViewCell` that you've configured to display the user defaults value.